# For what value of $p, q$ following series converges?

Tags: real-analysis

> Determine all values of $p$ and $q$ for which the following series converges:
>   $$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^q (\ln k)^p}$$

When $q=1$, It's easily checked by integral Test
But I'm struggling with $q<1$ and $q>1$

Maybe for $q>1$, if  $p\ge1$, by Comparison test with $\frac{1}{k^p}$, It converges.

and for $q<1$, if $p\le1$, by Comparison test with $1$, It diverges.

But what for $q>1$ with $p<1$ and $q<1$ with $p>1$??

I would appreciate to your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $q>1$ and $p<1$, it also converges. Let $\varepsilon=q-1>0$, and compare the limit with $\dfrac{1}{k^{1+\varepsilon/2}}$, which converges:
$$\lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{\dfrac{1}{k^q(\ln k)^p}}{\dfrac{1}{k^{1+\varepsilon/2}}}=\lim_{k\to \infty}\dfrac{1}{k^{\varepsilon/2}(\ln k)^p}=0$$

For $q<1$ it will always diverge. Compare  the limit with $\dfrac{1}{k}$:
$$\lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{\dfrac{1}{k}}{\dfrac{1}{k^q(\ln k)^p}}=\frac{(\ln k)^p}{k^{1-q}}=0$$

Answer (score 0):

The case : q>1 with p<1 can be dealt with by using this fact : q>1 => there is a h such as :

$1 < h < q$

Now the series $\sum \frac{1}{n^h} converges $ and if you let $U_k$ be the general term of your series you have : $U_k$ = o($\frac{1}{n^h}$) So your series converges, even if p<0.

The other is the same, with q < h < 1 and the divergence of the series : $\frac{1}{n^h}$ = o($U_k$) so if $\sum {U_k} $ converges, then $\sum \frac{1}{n^h}$ does as well, which isn't true

Comment: Of course, all of this is true because the general terms are both positive