# Determine for what values of P does the series converge

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

There is a similar question here: [For what value of $p, q$ following series converges?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/979531/for-what-value-of-p-q-following-series-converges)

In that question K is to the power of q a varible rather than raised to the power of $\frac{1}{2}$

$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}(k^p-1)}$$

I think the root test is supposed to be used but I am not sure how would this get set up?

Answer (score 1):

Note that, for $k\ge 2$ and $p>0$, 
$$
\frac{1}{k^{p+½}}\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}(k^p-1)}\le \frac{c}{k^{p+½}}
$$
where 
$$
\frac{2^{p}}{2^{p}-1}= c
$$
and hence
$\sum_{k\ge 2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}(k^p-1)}$
converges if and only if
$\sum_{k\ge 2}\frac{1}{k^{p+½}}$ converges, which happens if and only if $p+½>1$ or
$p>1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow it is like $\displaystyle\sum\dfrac{1}{k^{p+1/2}}$, this converges if and only if $p+1/2>1$.

Note that for $p>0$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k}(k^{p}-1)}}{\dfrac{1}{k^{p+1/2}}}=1,
\end{align*}
they are comparable.

For $p<0$, say, $p=-q$, $q>0$, we are in the situation that
\begin{align*}
\sum\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\dfrac{k^{q}}{1-k^{q}},
\end{align*}
the terms are negative, so it suffices to look at 
\begin{align*}
\sum\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\dfrac{k^{q}}{k^{q}-1},
\end{align*}
we compare with 
\begin{align*}
\sum\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k}}
\end{align*}
which is not convergent.

Note that 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\dfrac{k^{q}}{k^{q}-1}}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k}}}=1.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$k\ge 4$:

$(1/2)√kk^p\le √kk^p(1-1/√k)\le √kk^p;$

$\dfrac{1}{k^{p+1/2}} \le \dfrac{1}{k^{p+1/2}(1-1/√k)} \le$

$2\dfrac{1}{k^{p+1/2}}$.

Converges for $p>1/2$.